# Create and control call on behalf of user inside of Microsoft teams app/tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, azure-communication-services

I have been trying to find a solution inside of a Microsoft teams app/tab to make calls on behalve of users and actually be able to control the call.

I already tried making a call as a bot to both users, but that still leaves the bot in the call and both users are called by the bot instead of one user just calling the other.
I also tried to create a call with the microsoft teams sdk but then I have no control over the call.
Lastly I found the azure communications service which would fix the issue but then all the calls will be hosted on their servers which is also not an option for me.
So is there something I missed or is it just not possible?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Could you please share more details about your issue that what type of controll of calls you want exact here?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I mean by controlling a call is doing stuff like turning the camera on and off, transfering a call, parking a call, hanging up a call etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more details on the exact scenario you'd like to put in place? Inside your Teams app, do you want to call someone using your Teams identity by clicking on a button / link / on a specific event?

Regarding calling inside a Teams app, I think you've already identified most of the possible solutions:

- a bot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview
- using Azure Communication Services (ACS) with the Teams user identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-with-voice-video-calling-custom-teams-client
- based on what you'd like to achieve, the Graph API could potentially help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I have a list of contacts and want to be able to initiate a call with any of them when clicking a button. Then I want to be able to transfer said call to another person in those contacts by another button.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible via Teams identities placing and receiving calls via Azure Communication Services SDK.
Except call park, everything else should be doable.

Ref Document:
Communication as Teams user : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/teams-endpoint

How-Tos : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/cte-calling-sdk/manage-calls